# png images not loading

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

1.Why is my png not loading?

2.What would be a proper way to load my custom icons in my Soft skills and Hard skills tab individually.

3. How to divide my Hard and Soft skills in vertical pane and show my things

**In my data.js**

```
import creative from "./images/Creative.png";
import critical from "./images/critical.png";
import teamwork from "./images/Teamwork.png";
```

**Code from Skills.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Element } from "react-scroll";
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Tab, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useAppContext } from "../appContext";
import { Title } from "./globalStyledComponents";
import { skillData as hardSkillData, resume, SoftSkillData } from "../data";

export default function Skills() {
  const { theme } = useAppContext();

  // Separate the skill data into soft and hard skills
  const skillData = hardSkillData.filter((skill) => skill.type === "hard");
  const softSkills = SoftSkillData.filter((skill) => skill.type === "soft");

  return (
    <Element name={"Skills"} id="skills">
      <section className="section">
        <Container className="text-center">
          <Title>
            <h2>Skills</h2>
            <div className="underline"></div>
          </Title>
          {/* Use tabs component to create a navigation for soft and hard skills */}
          <Tab.Container defaultActiveKey="soft">
            <Row className="mt-3 align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <Col xs={12} md={6}>
                <Nav variant="pills" className="flex-column flex-md-row">
                  <Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Link eventKey="soft">Soft Skills</Nav.Link>
                  </Nav.Item>
                  <Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Link eventKey="hard">Hard Skills</Nav.Link>
                  </Nav.Item>
                </Nav>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            {/* Use tab content and tab pane components to render the skills sections */}
            <Tab.Content className="mt-3">
              {/* Soft skills section */}
              <Tab.Pane eventKey="soft">
                <Row className="align-items-center">
                  {SoftSkillData.map((skill) => {
                    return (
                      <Col xs={4} key={skill.name} className="my-md-5">
                        <figure>
                          <img src={softSkills.image} alt={softSkills.name} />
                          <figcaption>{skill.name}{skill.image}</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                      </Col>
                    );
                  })}
                </Row>
              </Tab.Pane>
              {/* Hard skills section */}
              <Tab.Pane eventKey="hard">
                <Row className="align-items-center">
                  {skillData.map((skill) => {
                    return (
                      <Col xs={4} key={skillData.name} className="my-md-5">
                        <figure>
                          <img src={skillData.skill} alt={skillData.name} />
                          <figcaption>{skillData.name}</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                      </Col>
                    );
                  })}
                </Row>
              </Tab.Pane>
            </Tab.Content>
          </Tab.Container>

          {resume && (
            <a href={resume}>
              <Button
                size="lg"
                variant={theme === "light" ? "outline-dark" : "outline-light"}
                className="mt-5"
              >
                R&eacute;sum&eacute;
              </Button>
            </a>
          )}
        </Container>
      </section>
    </Element>
  );
}
```

[image: Code Output]

I tried renaming the variables. Tried ChatGpt to debug but no fruitful answers.

Comment: Try to check the URL path. Appears the folder static in your picture,  could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that happens for some reason the engine gets lost with path from images and other files.
Using require in the img tag will solve your problem

```
<img src={require('../../wherever path it is')} alt=""/>
```